# How can I designate a default email account in Apple Mail on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, email

Opening a new mail to compose currently defaults to the Cloud email.

I want to change that default to my Gmail (set up already in Apple Mail).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The default mail is the first one in the list. So just move it up in the preferences.